# Convert plain text to string literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, is there any way to convert plain text (with special characters) to a JavaScript string literal?

For example, is there any way to convert the following text to a string literal?

```
"Here is some text inside quotes."Here is more text inside quotes: it's not easy to write this as a string literal, so I need to automatically convert it somehow." "
```

Comment: Where's the text coming from? It might be easier to deal with the double-quoted/nested-quoted strings as they're created.

Comment: I really dont understand the question ... where is the text coming from ? surely its already a string literal ?

Comment: @DavidThomas In that case, I'd need to type in escape characters for every quotation mark (and every other special character) inside the string. It is sometimes necessary to embed HTML in JavaScript as a string, which is the main use case that I have in mind.

Comment: Not necessarily, but without knowing where it's coming from it's difficult to suggest any alternative. More information tends to lead to better answers. You may be correct, this might be *precisely* what you have to do, but  there's always a chance there's a better approach. See '[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)' on [meta].

Comment: Noone seems to understand the question here.
He.. and also I .. looking for a generator.. like google translate.. that if you put a text in the generator it gives you a valid JS string.

Comment: `str.replace(/\r?\n|\r|\u2028|\u2029/gm, '\\n').replace(/\t/g, '\\t').replace(/"/g, '\\\"').replace(/'/g, "\\'");` Replacing tabulations is optional.